# Get currently playing music app

Tags: android, audio-player, android-music-player

I am using this tutorial and the RemoteController to control the currently playing music player:

http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2579415

Is there a way to get the application/package of the currently playing music application? I want to be able to open it.

I'm sure it is possible somehow as Aviate manages to do it, but afaict this class does not provide that information:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/RemoteController.OnClientUpdateListener.html

Maybe there is some unrelated way of getting the currently playing music player...

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I worked it out... had to use reflection on the RemoteController though.

```
Method method = mRemoteController.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("getRemoteControlClientPackageName");
if (method != null) {
    return (String) method.invoke(mRemoteController);
}
```